# Demonstrating how to turn the affine plane into a double-cone with a sheet of paper, is it possible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, affine-varieties

I am currently learning a little bit about algebraic groups and quotients of varieties with J. Harris book "Algebraic Geometry" (http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/aconstant/Alg2/Bib/Harris_AlgebraicGeometry.pdf). Here, in example 10.21 (page 125), he shows that the quotient of the affine plane $\mathbb{A}^2$ under the group action $(x,y) \mapsto (-x,-y)$ is a quadric cone in $\mathbb{A}^3$. I understand, why that is the case: The invariant ring $K[X,Y]^G$ is isomorphic to $K[X,Y,Z] / (X^2 + Y^2 - Z^2)$, so the quotient is given by the equation $X^2 + Y^2 = Z^2$ which is precisely the equation of a quadric cone. However, there is also this picture in the book:

[image]

Sadly, there is no further explanation to this picture, especially it's not clear for me, what the diagonal lines should indicate. Then a thought came to my mind: What if it's possible to turn the affine plane into the quadric cone in a intuitive way, by cutting the affine plane into pieces, and glueing those pieces together to end up with a cone, where a point on the cone uniquely corresponds to a pair of points $a,b$ (or one point if we are at the origin), s.t. $a=(x,y), b=(-x,-y)$. Maybe these diagonal lines are the lines where we cut the affine plane into pieces. I tried it with a paper: I put the origin into the middle of the paper and cutted along the diagonals, getting 4 triangles. Now we just take any triangle, for example the upper triangle, and glue it onto the triangle on the opposite site, so the lower triangle, s.t. points $(x,y)$ and $(-x,-y)$ get glued together. Now we glue the left triangle onto the right triangle in the same way, ending up with 2 triangles. These two triangles can be glued together at their edges, again we only glue those edges together that represent the same points.

This way, we end up with a a "mono-cone" (a cone with only one nappe), and each point of this mono-cone corresponds uniquely to a pair of points $(x,y), (-x,-y)$, except at the origin. However, we wanted to get a cone, and not just a mono-cone. So my question is: Is it possible to do some kind of similar construction but end up with a cone instead? I tried cutting the plane into 8 pieces, by additionally cutting along the axes. We again glue our 8 triangles together and end up with 4 triangles, now my idea was that we could basically glue two triangles respectively together at their edges and end up with a cone, however this is not really possible because we would have to glue edges together that do not represent the same points, so a point on our cone could then actually have 4 corresponding points on the plane, so this idea does not really work. Is there some intuitive way to do it?

Comment: The other half of the cone comes from complex points, so your diagram will need some adjustment (or you'll have to just kind of accept that the picture has this shortcoming). To explain what I mean, if $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates on the plane, then $t=x^2$, $u=y^2$, and $v=xy$ are the coordinates on the cone, and these embed the cone as the zero locus of $tu-v^2$ in $\Bbb A^3$. The only way to get $t<0$ or $u<0$ (this is what happens on the "other half" of the cone) is if $x$ or $y$ is imaginary, respectively.